# Buy real life thing inside my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Hi every one Can I buy inside my app one thing like one t-shirt,
I know `In App Purchase` can't works because t-shirt is a real life thing but
i dont want the payment outside the app like in safari.
I like to be the payment inside my app,registering a credit card and buy the item,
like this apps `Amazon, Airbnb` how the payment inside this apps works?

I've read a lot of information about that and all the people say the only way to make payments inside the app is with `In App Purchase` but how this apps i've mentioned works, because i can make the payment inside this apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PayPal API is free, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584063/paypal-api-how-to-integrate-it-in-my-app-ios5) you can find a nice example on how to integrate it.
Most important is that you may not use the PayPal API for Digital goods...

and one [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779423/has-anyone-implemented-the-paypal-api-through-a-native-iphone-app)

Comment: hi @Frank in theory I can make a purchase inside my app if the thing is like jeans, Food, etc. I'm Right? I can register my credit card and implement my own payment platform?

Comment: Yes, PayPal will alow you to do that. Your own payment platform, sure... but there are a lot of regulations aroud that like PCI, will be more dificult then just integrating PayPal

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple systems you can leverage out there. You could take a look at [Paypal's IPN](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) and [Google Checkout](https://developers.google.com/checkout/).

Comment: They're APIs. Technically, you don't need a browser to use them. For iOS, for example, you can use NSURLConnections to communicate with them.

Comment: Hi thanks @Simon you now if i have to pay something to work with those APIs.