# integrate paypal standard in iphone application

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am developing iphone application for a shopping cart, i have done all stuffs but now its turn for online payment, the web version support paypal standard and the client want to stick with paypal standard the user will be redirected and paypal site and log and complete order. Is this possible on iphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some days before apple does not allow any third party payment gateway. But now apple allows it to use the third party payment gateway like Paypal. You can used paypal library which allows you to pay your payment of products which you purchased from the app. For doing all this, paypal provides the library for mobile application development. I had used it in my 3-4 apps & works fine for me.

may be this could help you
[link](http://www.alexanderjaeger.de/paypal-ios-sdk/)
[link](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation)

Download Mobile Express Checkout Library from [library](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-express-checkout-library) and add the same to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Why not you using PayPal SDk for Mobile device ? I have integrated PayPal in my app through their MPL library and Modified some stuffs like App Key and price,Store name Receiver account details etc. And its working fine for me.

check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584063/paypal-api-how-to-integrate-it-in-my-app-ios5) which is Already answered.

Also you can have a look at [Getting started Guide](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/quick-start-guides/mobile-payments-library-ios-getting-started).

[PayPal API : How to integrate it in my App? IOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584063/paypal-api-how-to-integrate-it-in-my-app-ios5)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.paypal.com/

You need to implement paypal on your web server first.

Then go to that link from UIWebview….